# How do I get the Mirth Connect Environment Name in a script?

Tags: javascript, mirth

I'm running Mirth Connect Server 3.8.1. The settings page has two fields, Environment Name and Server Name:

[image]

I've been able to get the Server Name in a script the following way:

```
var configurationController = Packages.com.mirth.connect.server.controllers.ConfigurationController.getInstance();
var serverName = configurationController.getServerName();
```

But I have not been able to get the Environment Name. The obvious guess that didn't work and only resulted in an error was:

```
var environmentName = configurationController.getEnvironmentName();
```

How to get this field?

Comment: Future reference for anyone arriving here: the full list of methods available on ConfigurationController can be found [here](https://github.com/nextgenhealthcare/connect/blob/86fe07b42d5513ca36c4e0521de23a98f59c8edd/server/src/com/mirth/connect/server/controllers/ConfigurationController.java#L41).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work.

```
var serverSettings = configurationController.getServerSettings();
var environmentName = serverSettings.getEnvironmentName();
```

The serverSettings object also has the server name available among other settings. See source here:
https://github.com/nextgenhealthcare/connect/blob/3.8.x/server/src/com/mirth/connect/model/ServerSettings.java

Answer (score 1):

For folks finding this thread, here's a function that returns the Mirth environment name.

```
function getEnvironmentName () {
var configurationController = Packages.com.mirth.connect.server.controllers.ConfigurationController.getInstance();
var serverSettings = configurationController.getServerSettings();
var environmentName = serverSettings.getEnvironmentName();
return environmentName;
```

}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).